# Google Data Studio can't explore Big Query time partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

When trying to explore a Big Query Table in Google Data Studio after having connected to it I get the following error. Any Ideas how to handle that or what it means?

> The query returned an error.
>
> Unrecognized name: _PARTITIONTIME at [1:167] Error ID: a6e0a88c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Data Studio editor, click resources --> manage added data sources  then go to edit connection.

There is an option to use _PARTITIONTIME as the time dimension. 
I suspect Data Studio has picked up this magic field and tried to use it as a time datatype and there is some incompatibility going on. I think this field is really metadata so shouldn't be used. Data Studio should really ignore it and not try to be too clever in finding your fields and inferring their usage & type from their names ( Although, mostly that is helpful ).

Unticking that option, clicking back to the report with `Done` will let you resolve the issue.

[image: Click Resource then Manage added data sources]

[image: Click edit connection]

[image: Untick Use _PARTITIONTIME as time dimension]

Comment: After reading all about partitioned tables in BQ, it _seems_ like you should check that box. But this answer is right on and fixed this error. Thanks!

Comment: BigQuery would assign `_PARTITIONTIME` as the timestamp when data is ingested (loaded) into the table. You can manually set a date column in the data as a partition key instead, and in that case you would probably be OK to check off the box